# scrapy deny localized urls

Tags: python, regex, localization, scrapy

I m trying to deny localized URLS as follows:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'\/es\/')), follow = True)
)
```

However this fail. Tried other regexes like the following but not luck.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'\/es\/*.*')), follow = True)
)
```

Essentially I am only interested in the english version of the resource. Not a version that is spanish, ie: it has `/es/` in the URL.

How can I ensure I am not crawling spanish URLs?

Comment: Best and easy way is to use a mddleware and ignore any URL inside `process_request` method

Comment: there is no `process_request` method defined for middleware though?

Comment: I am not sure what you said, you just create a download middleware file and inside process_request of that method access the url via request.url and then decide whether to scrape this url or ignore it. PS: process_request is called before a url is scraped.

Comment: I am saying there is no such method `process_request` in the middleware. see : https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=middleware#writing-your-own-spider-middleware

Comment: See my answer .... You were looking at the Spider middlewares, while I mentioned about Download middlewares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your middleware in your spider like this

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"  

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'project_root_path.MyMiddlewaresFile.MyMiddleware': 300,

        }
    }


    def start_requests(self):

        yield Request()
```

and in your `MyMiddlewaresFile.py`

```
class MyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if "/en/" in request.url:
            pass #Do not do anything.

        else:
            #keep processing request
            return request
```

See docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request